# How to move two row values to column and respective row in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

Below is the XML output where I have to extract the values from details fields- 1st value as column name and 2nd value as its value in a row.

Example: Column Name - renamedCount and its row value as 64
         Column Name -successUpdateCount and its row value as 64 
and so on..

```
    <root>

     <details>
     <values>renamedCount</values>
     <values>64</values>
     <values>successUpdateCount</values>
     <values>64</values>
     <values>totalCreateCount</values>
     <values>0</values>
     <values>successRowCount</values>
     <values>64</values>
     <values>invalidCount</values>
     <values>0</values>
     <values>totalUpdateCount</values>
     <values>4211</values>
     <values>failedCount</values>
     <values>64</values>
     <values>totalRowCount</values>
     <values>0</values>
     <values>4275</values>
     <occurrences>0</occurrences>
     <localMessageText>Accounts: 64 (0/64) rows successful, 4211 ignored </localMessageText>
     <type>hierarchyRowsProcessed</type>
  </details>
  <details>
</root>
```

Please suggest how to assign one value as a variable name and second one as it value?

Thanks in advance for the support,
Kelly

Answer (score 0):

A grouping or windowing clause would help here.

For example, one can compute the row number with an integer division by 2, and group values with it:

```
let $doc :=
  <root>
    <details>
      <values>renamedCount</values>
      <values>64</values>
      <values>successUpdateCount</values>
      <values>64</values>
      <values>totalCreateCount</values>
      <values>0</values>
      <values>successRowCount</values>
      <values>64</values>
      <values>invalidCount</values>
      <values>0</values>
      <values>totalUpdateCount</values>
      <values>4211</values>
      <values>failedCount</values>
      <values>64</values>
      <values>totalRowCount</values>
      <values>0</values>
      <values>4275</values>
      <occurrences>0</occurrences>
      <localMessageText>Accounts: 64 (0/64) rows successful,
        4211 ignored </localMessageText>
      <type>hierarchyRowsProcessed</type>
   </details>
 </root>
for $values at $pos in $doc/details/values
let $row-number := ($pos + 1) idiv 2
group by $row-number
return <row number="{$row-number}">{$values}</row>
```

It requires XQuery 3.0 for both grouping and windowing. The query can be tested with Zorba [here](http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/Gm+fxcaL3gR/yTz7LUx4a7K6Lm4=).